# d3 - change x axis interval

Tags: javascript, typescript, d3.js

I need help with a d3 line chart.

The X axis looks weird, how to skip every X label's, same like I have in the Y axis?

[image]

---

Working example:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-7awftc?file=App.tsx

Comment: @0stone0 i'm asking about d3 but you paste docs to the different chart library???

Comment: Sorry, completely misread the question. I've removed that useless comment. After some searchig was able to [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75792715/5625547) your question(s).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Issue 1

Your `lineGenerator` does not generate the `Scale`, you'll need to uncomment these

```
const lineGenerator = d3.line()
    // .x(d => xScale(d.date))
    // .y(d => yScale(d.visits))
    .curve(d3.curveMonotoneX);
```

---

#### Issue 2 (skip every X label)

In your `XYAxis`, you need to implement [`tickValues`](https://d3-wiki.readthedocs.io/zh_CN/master/SVG-Axes/#tickValues).

So since you just want this on `xAxis`, I've abused `if (orient === 'bottom')`  to only apply this for the `xAxis` (this should be improved ofc), but it comes down to:

```
axis = d3.axisBottom(scale).tickValues(
    scale.domain().filter(function (d, i) {
        return !(i % 100);
    })
);
```

Were we use [remainder (`%`) operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Remainder) to only show the `tick` every `100` items (`i % 100`)

---

Your final result looks like:
[image]

Which you can try for yourself in this updated StackBlitz:

##### [Online demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-mwaujs?file=LineChart.tsx,XYAxis.tsx)

Comment: @0strone0 if you open your example in the browser
https://react-ts-mwaujs.stackblitz.io/
 you will get an error like
`Error: <path> attribute d: Expected number, "MNaN,NaNCNaN,NaN,…".`

Comment: Oke I think that it's caused by your 'initialData'. You're using the `name` and `value`, but that needs to be `return {
        date: d.date,
        visits: 0,
      };`

Comment: somehow I've missed that! THANKS!!